# Filter a list of pairs (tuples) where the tuple doesn't include any value from another list

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list of tuples:

```
my_list = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(7,8)]
```

and a list of values I want to exclude which are in the format:

```
reference_list = [(2,20),(3,46),(4,918)]
```

The value I want to exclude is the first of the pair. (The meaning of the 20, 46, 918 isn't important)

So I would want to return a list of tuples that don't include any of the 2,3, 4 values.

#### Expected result:

```
[(5,6),(7,8)]
```

(because all the others contain one or more of the values 2, 3 or 4)

What I've tried:

```
[p for p in my_list if p[0] not in [v[0] for v in reference_list] and p[1] not in [v[0] for v in reference_list]]
```

I'm checking for the first or second value of the pair not being in the list v[0] of the reference list.

It does work but I am looking for a more concise/pythonic way, if any. Ideally extendable (without just adding conditions like p[2] not in list and p[3] not in list and.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flat is better than nested

```
blacklist = {p[0] for p in blacklist_of_tuples}
[p for p in my_list if p[0] not in blacklist and p[1] not in blacklist]
```

This doesn't solve the generalized case, but you can do so with a dash of [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
[p for p in my_list if not any(el in blacklist for el in p)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list-comprehension with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
[x for x in lst1 if not any(y[0] in x for y in lst2)]
```

**Code**:

```
lst1 = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(7,8)]
lst2 = [(2,20),(3,46),(4,918)] 

set_lst2 = set(lst2)
print([x for x in lst1 if not any(y[0] in x for y in set_lst2)])
# [(5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Comment: The conversion to `set` actually slows things down here: firstly, you are using the set for iteration instead of membership checking, which is much slower than using a list. Also, you are reconstructing a set every single iteration.

Comment: @Tomothy32, `set` is faster in cases where there are multiple duplicates in second list, but I agree on reconstruction on every iteration. Fixed that.

Comment: I hate to be pedantic here, but the cost of iterating over a set is much greater than the cost of a few extra iterations (unless, of course, the list is mostly composed of duplicates). Anyway, nice answer, I'll leave you an upvote. :)

Comment: @Tomothy32, oh! ya. You were talking about membership check is faster than the set for iteration (+1). I better leave this as it already is as the same is covered in another answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons for larger lists, you should make a set that contains the first elements of the second list:

```
list_a = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(7,8)]
list_b = [(2,20),(3,46),(4,918)]

set_b = {t[0] for t in list_b}

result = [t for t in list_a if not set_b.intersection(t)]
```

In general, the `intersection` method is a bit faster than `any`:

```
%timeit [t for t in list_a if not set_b.intersection(t)]
2.7 µs ± 377 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit [t for t in list_a if not any(el in set_b for el in t)]
4.97 µs ± 479 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```